# Datadog Log Search - how to show CONTENT column?

Tags: datadog

Sometimes, I need to remove CONTENT, sometimes, I need to use CONTENT.
How to show or add CONTENT column?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the options tab you can toggle the content column

[image: log page screenshot]

Comment: Is there any way to achieve same through URL Query parameters ?

Comment: I believe saved views will remember the columns you have chosen. So using a saved view might help